# Why does `singularity run/exec` automatically bind specific some directories? What is the use case?

Tags: singularity-container

I'm familiar with containers, but new to Singularity and I found myself fighting a broken Python installation in a Singularity container tonight. It turns out that this was because `$HOME` was being mounted into my container without my knowledge.

I guess that I've developed a liking for the idiom "Explicit is better than implicit" from Python. To me, automatically mounting specific directories is unexpected behavior.

Three questions:

1. Why does Singularity default to mounting $HOME, /tmp, /proc, etc?
2. So that I can become more comfortable with Singularity, what are some use cases for this behavior?
3. I see the `--no-home` flag, but is there a flag to disable all of the default mounts without needing to change the default Singularity configuration?

Comment: FWIW this is the part of the doc relevant to this question: https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.1/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a mixture of design, convenience and technical necessity.

The biggest reason is that, unless you use certain params that say otherwise, Singularity images are read-only filesystems. You need somewhere to write output and any temporary files that get created along the way. Maybe you know to mount in your output dir, but there are all sorts of files that get created / modified / deleted in the background that we don't ever think about. Implicit automounts give reasonable defaults that work in most situations.

Simplistic example: you're doing a big `sort` and filter operation on some data, but you're print the results to console so you don't bother to mount in anything but the raw data. But even after some manipulation and filtering, the size of the data exceeds available memory so sort falls back to using small files in `/tmp` before being deleted when the process finishes. And then it crashes because you can't write to `/tmp`.

You can require a user to manually specify a what to mount to `/tmp` on run, or you can use a sane default like `/tmp` and also allow that to be overridden by the user (`SINGULARITY_TMPDIR`, `-B $PWD/fake_tmp:/tmp`, `--contain/--containall`). These are all also configurable, so the admins can set sane defaults specific the running environment.

There are also technical reasons for some of the mounts. *e.g.,* `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` are needed to match permissions on the host OS. The docs on [bind paths and mounts](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html) are actually pretty good and have more specifics on the whats and whys, and even the answer to your third question: `--no-mount`. The `--contain/--containall` flags will probably also be of interest. If you *really* want to deep dive, there are also the [admin docs](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/admin-guide/configfiles.html) and the [source code on github](https://github.com/hpcng/singularity).

---

A simple but real singularity use case, with explanation:

```sh
singularity exec \
    --cleanenv \
    -H $PWD:/home \
    -B /some/local/data:/data \
    multiqc.sif \
    multiqc -i $SAMPLE_ID /data
```

`--cleanenv / -e`: You've already experienced the fun of unexpected mounts, there's also unexpected environment variables! `--cleanenv/-e` tells Singularity to not persist the host execution environment in the container. You can still use, e.g.,  `SINGULARITYENV_SOMEVAR=23` to have `SOMEVAR=23` inside the container though, as that is explicitly set.

`-H $PWD:/home`: This mounts the current directory into the container to `/home` and sets `HOME=/home`. While using `--contain/--containall` and explicit mounts is probably a better solution, I am lazy and this ensures several things:

1. the current directory is mounted into the container. The implicit mounting of the working is allowed to fail, and will do so quietly, if the base directory does not exist in the image. e.g., if you're running from `/cluster/my-lab/some-project` and there is no `/cluster` inside your image, it will not be mounted in. This is not an issue if using explicit binds directly (`-B /cluster/my-lab/some-project`) or if an explicit bind has a shared path (`-B /cluster/data/experiment-123`) with current directory.
2. the command is executed from the context of the current directory. If `$PWD` fails to be mounted as described above, singularity uses `$HOME` as the working directory instead. If both `$PWD` and `$HOME` failed to mount, `/` is used. This can cause problems if you're using relative paths and you aren't where you expected to be. Since it is specific to the path on the host, it can be *really* annoying when trying to duplicate a problem locally.
3. the base path is inside the container is always the same regardless of host OS file structure. Consistency is good.

The rest is just the command that's being run, which in this case summarizes the logs from other programs that work with genetic data.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is exactly what I was looking for and hit all of the points I needed to understand. I really appreciate the time that you took to write this up! The only part that doesn't make sense to me yet is the `--contain/--containall` flags, but I expect that will make more sense with more use.